# printing in reactjs without showing the printing dialog modal

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF file without showing the printing dialog modal in my ReactJS or Laravel application. I've tried several libraries, but none of them seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

i tried using print-js library and some other libraries in reactjs and laravel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.